# What Is the First Same Sex Relationship in Science Fiction?

Tags: history-of, sexuality

This came up in a talk with someone recently.  Science Fiction is a genre that often prides itself of being ahead of the curve on many things, but, as best I can remember, the first same-sex relationship in SF in popular media was in *Babylon 5* in the 1990s.

What is the earliest instance of a same-sex relationship in SF (or fantasy, as well)?

Comment: I don't know if it's the first, but Arthur C. Clarke's *Imperial Earth* (1975) had its fair share of bisexuality.

Comment: Deafening silence on the TV & film part of the question.

Comment: @KyleJones: Yes, I noticed that, too.

Comment: @TangoOversway - I'm on strike till you make the TV thing a separate question. First, because I didn't bother reading till the end. Second, because it makes for a better, cleaner question. Third, because I'm a rep Julia Roberts

Comment: @DVK: You're a rep whore, not a rep slut.  But that's a good point -- you sure people won't start screaming, "But it's a duplicate?"  Well, there's no TV/movie answers, so I'll make that change.

Comment: @Tango - "Pretty woman"?!?!?!

Comment: @DVK: I'll thank you not to remind me of that.  I remember my ex watching it many times in one weekend until I was sick from it.  I try to forget it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, if you include "Fantasy", you gotta start with Ancient Greek myths (e.g. Zephyr and Hyakinthos).

If you don't, [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_themes_in_speculative_fiction#Proto-SF) lists

> True History by the Greek writer Lucian (A.D. 120–185) has been called the earliest surviving example of science fiction and the first ever "gay science fiction story".

Wiki Sources:

- Fredericks, S.C.: “Lucian's True History as SF”, Science Fiction Studies, Vol. 3, No. 1 (March 1976), pp. 49–60
- Gunn, James E. denotes True History as "Proto-Science Fiction", p.249
- Lynne Yamaguchi Fletcher The First Gay Pope and other records, p. 95, Alyson Publications: 1992 ISBN 978-1555832063

For later "real SF", Wiki lists:

> *An Anglo-American Alliance*, a 1906 novel by Gregory Casparian, was the first SF-themed novel to openly portray a lesbian romantic relationship.

Answer (score 2):

For SF magazines, I believe the answer is ["The World Well Lost"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_World_Well_Lost) by Theodore Sturgeon, published in 1953.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say "Stranger in a Strange Land" by Robert Anson Heinlein written in 1961

lots of sex and orgies and quite a bit of woman on woman action.

Comment: but not really relationships, I wouldn't say.

Comment: The group "marriage" that takes place in the book and the sexual intercourse between the co-wives forms part of the core relationship between Mike.  It is however not a monogamous relationship more of a set loosely coupled (pardon the pun) relationships within the group where sometimes the match up were same-sex.

Comment: While a good answer, it's definitely **not the first**

Comment: Well, that Heinlein predates Harry Harrison's 'Star Smashers of the Galaxy Rangers' by 12 years.